# C++ "does not have a name type" error while using auto

Tags: c++, string, auto

I seem to have a problem with iterators while using the auto type. Below u will find a minimal working example I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string s("some string");
    for(auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end() && !isspace(*it); ++it)
        *it = toupper(*it);
    cout<< "string is : " << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This small program tries to convert the letters of a first word of a string to uppercase. When i try to compile it however I get the following error message:
error: ‘it’ does not name a type
  for(auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end() && !isspace(*it); ++it)
Does anyone know why the compiler says it doesn't have a type? I'm using the latest version of g++.

Comment: have you enabled a C++11 mode with `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: Before C++11, `auto` was a storage class like `static`, and the identifier following it should be the name of a type  - as in `auto int x;` - hence the message "'it' does not name a type".

Comment: I did enable c++ 11 mode as Piotr suggested. This seemed to make no difference.